# std::vector incredible memory leak

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, memory-leaks, stl

can somebody explain me this bug (replicable):

```
int foo();

int main() {
    foo();
    return 1;
}

int foo() {
    std::vector<double> test;
    int c=0;
    c++;
}
```

This code as far as I know should not present memory leaks. When executing it in debug mode, and putting a break point in the first line of `foo()`, the memory increases until I don't stop the process (in 10 seconds it reaches 2.5 GB).

I'm using `G++` and `Qt-creator`. Is there something I don't know about `std::vector` or have I just discovered a bug?

PS: this is C++98

Comment: This looks like a bug with the debugger...

Comment: `foo` seems to be pretty simple - if this is allocating memory over time in the debugger, the debugger must be re-evaluating some expression over and over. Likely it keeps recreating `test`.

Comment: oh jes.. what a bad luck.. this was driving me crazy.. I think you are right because when I execute it there's no memory leak.. so I've found a bug in GDB..

Comment: That may not be leak, it could be memory fragmentation. What happens when you let it run for few minutes ?

Comment: And that code compiles without function `foo` returning anything?

Comment: Behavior is not replicated on ubuntu 13.10 with g++ 4.8.1 version.

Comment: Guys I've found a solution. I've solved disabling the "load system GDB pretty printers" option in my Qt-creator 3.1.0

Comment: @Raydel Miranda it does, going to check the other option set to five me all the errors.

Comment: @PankajM as I said after 10-15 seconds the gdb memory consumption goes to 2.5 GB and the system blocks itself

Comment: @RaydelMiranda You are not required to return a value for the program to compile. It just has undefined behavior if you don't.